# Rails 3 - rspec conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm working through the "Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example" by Michael Hartl (2011) and I've run into a conflict with rspec. Now when I try to run rspec I get:

```
rspec spec/
/home/bill44077/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@global/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:27:in `block in setup': You have already activated rspec-core 2.5.1, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.4.0. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I looked in my Gemfile and I don't see a revision requirement for rspec. I tried

```
gem uninstall rspec-rails 
bundle install
```

but that didn't seem to help. If I run

```
bundle exec rspec spec/
```

that works fine but I really want to run autotest as I was before so I need to get rspec working again as it was.

Any ideas what I need to do to solve this version problem?

thanks!!
Bill

Comment: Just found this: bundle update rspec
bundle update rspec-rails
Seems to have fixed it. Autotest now runs. (Need to understand what's going on here though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because even though you did not specify a version of rspec in your gemfile, in your Gemfile.lock it will have stored the version (2.4.0 it looks like in this case).

Then, when you ran the command `rspec` it was trying to use a newer version than the locked one. Running `bundle update rspec` will have updated the 'locked' version in Gemfile.lock, which, as you found, will sort it all out.

Comment: Thanks idlefingers! Appreciate the explanation.